# Error calling stored procedure that have been created in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have this procedure :

```
USE [base1]  
GO

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'dbo.MyProcedure ', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure ;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure 
                            @code NVARCHAR(1000),
                            @Month    INT,
                            @YEAR     INT
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- my code
GO
-- END PROCEDURE
```

I use the procedure by following steps :

1. To create it i execute the script of procedure
2. The procedure is create in this database `base1 not in master`
3. I launch this command `EXECUTE dbo.MyProcedure N'Test',03,2016;` => i get the succesfull result
4. I disconnect from the server and i reconnect
5. I execute this : `CEXECUTE dbo.MyProcedure N'Test',03,2016;`  => i get this error 
   `Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.MyProcedure'.`

So in custom database  `base1>Programmability >stored procedures =>` i can see the procedure it exists

Comment: You executing in the right database context? Will default to `master` when connecting unless you specify.

Comment: I created it in my custom database using  `USE [base1] GO` and  i execute it like this :`EXECUTE dbo.MyProcedure N'test',03,2016;`

Comment: Don't you think that would be relevant information in the question? Takes two seconds to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35777627/edit).

Comment: and what happens if you execute it as: `EXECUTE base1.dbo.MyProcedure N'test',03,2016;`?

Comment: The `USE [base1]` in your `CREATE PROCEDURE` script only applies while executing that command. Are you sure when you `EXECUTE dbo.MyProcedure N'test',03,2016;` you are also using `USE [base1]` or `EXECUTE base1.dbo.MyProcedure N'test',03,2016;` to fully qualify the database?

Comment: @Lankymart  i edit my question

Comment: you still haven't tried executing your procedure with `EXECUTE base1.dbo.MyProcedure....`

Comment: @Lamak Òh yes it's work. thanks!

Comment: When you disconnect you lose the database context *(`base1`)* and once it reconnects it defaults to `master` where your stored procedure doesn't exist, which is why I suggested `USE [base1] GO EXECUTE...` when calling your procedure or `EXECUTE base1.dbo......`.

Comment: Thanks for this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, default database on connection is `master`.  so when you disconnected and reconnected, you most likely are in `master` database.  You can verify by executing `SELECT DB_NAME()`.  Since you created your proc in a different database, execution will fail until you switch databases or fully qualify your proc call.